# wordpress how to sort posts on custom data with plug-in "Search & Filter"

Tags: shortcode

I would like to sort my articles, according to personalized data (3 fields which have been added via a php script),
I see them well (in my admin dashboard) when I consult my articles (3 new columns are clearly visible for each article).
I was able to enter data (via custom Fields) in edit mode for all items.

I installed the "Search and Filter" plugin (free version), so I got the example of the following shortcode for the sorting part:

[searchandfilter fields=”search,category,post_tag” order_dir=”,asc,desc” order_by=”,id,name” types=”,checkbox,radio” headings=”,Categories,Tags”]

that I adapted by adding my new sorting field (number_runners) and inserting it into my page
but it never takes into account the new sorting..., I'm not sure if I should leave headings and tags at the end??.

**[searchandfilter fields=”search,category,post_tag” order_dir=”asc” order_by=”number_runners” types=”radio” headings=”Tags”]**

when I view the page, it offers me a drop-down list with the categories and a submit button but when I execute:
the sort order always remains the same, always the default one (by article creation date)
so it never takes into account the "order by number_runners" (I had to crash on the adaptation of the shortcode!! not easy:-0!...
and I started on WP only a few months ago ;-(( )
(and is there a way then to display this data in the drop-down list because I actually have 3 fields, 3 sorting criteria)??

Thank you very much for your advice or experiences! because I have a lot of trouble with it!! :-((

Rem: *I have the "hueman" theme and in the plug-in it specifies that if a theme file is used, the shortcode must be preceded by: <?php echo do_shortcode....*  ??

Comment: hello ,
still no ideas....I think I'm already using the wrong plugin and I think the solution is to make a php sort script with maybe an array?? but I don't know at all how to do it and then be able to activate it from the page via a radio button or something else for example.

Comment: When you use third party plugins you'll need to refer to their documentation and support channels to get advice on stuff like this.  Few people on here (if any) have any idea what that shortcode is attempting to do, so it's not likely that any of us can advise you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
In fact I would simply like to be able to sort my articles according to the personal fields that I created with the ACF plug-in (Advanced Custon Fields)
 , then I used the Search & Filter plug-in for sorting but I can't do it... (I've already consulted their documentation before posting on this forum)
so my question now is is there another way (therefore without a plug-in) to activate this sorting via a script? (do we have to write code? but I don't have any examples) and if so,
then, how to activate it on my page via a radio button for example??